# Не получается отобразить название аккаунта в терминале (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Дело в том что я хочу, чтобы когда кто то писал 'test' мне бы писало в терминал кто это написал (ник)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
  if message.content == "test":
      print(f'Человек {ctx.user.name} использовал мат')
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

но у меня появляется ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):                                  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event                        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test":
        print(f'Человек {str(message.author)} использовал мат! Стыд и позор!')
```

Например у меня это делается так:

[image: сообщение]

[image: окно консоли]